# Typescript type hinting inside dot notation

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface IRenderStruct {
  type: string;
  props: {
    className?: string;
    children?: (string | IRenderStruct) | (string | IRenderStruct)[];
    [propName: string]: any;
  };
}
```

So resulting objects may be nested inside via `elm.props.children`. I am now creating some unit tests and in one case, I *know* that I will have a RenderStruct object as children of another. No string as children, and also no array of RenderStruct objects as children.

But when I want to do this:

`expect(result.props.children.type === 'something');`

The TS compiler complains that I cannot access `type` because `children` *may* be a string and that doesnt have the property `type`.

Okay, TS - you are correct! But I definitely know that in this case we will have the nested structure. How do I tell TS that its the case?

Comment: For this test u might need to use isFish()  http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html 
And then cast it properly to do the test

Answer (score 0):

Create an user-defined type guard to check it:

```
var render: IRenderStruct;

// function to check if something is an IRenderStruct:
function isIRenderStruct(p: any): p is IRenderStruct {
    return ('props' in p) && ('type' in p);
}

let b: boolean;
if (isIRenderStruct(render.props.children)) {
    b = render.props.children.type === 'something'; // No errors
}
```

**EDIT**:

For the specific case of your test, you can do:

```
let test = false;
if (isIRenderStruct(render.props.children)) {
    test = render.props.children.type === 'something'; // No errors
}

expect(test).toBeTruthy();
```

this way, you avoid `else`s. If the guard fails, `test` will be `false` and your test will fail. This way you can even get a broader range of errors.

Comment: This works, but also gives an interesting case: if the guard fails, my unit test expect check is never performed :)

For now did this: `if(guard) { ... } else expect(false).toBeTruthy()` but god, this is ugly... :(

Comment: Check my answer again